# RVM - Multilib version error installing libffi-devel on Centos 6.6

Tags: installation, centos, rvm

I have a Digital Ocean droplet running CentOS release 6.6 and I need to install Ruby and Capistrano on it.  I've been following this idiot's guide;

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-capistrano-to-automate-deployments-getting-started

but I've run into a problem at the command `rvm install 2.1.0`.

Basically the install script tries to install the package `libffi-devel` but cannot.  Throws an error saying there's a Multilib version problem I need to resolve and suggesting some remedies.  None of them seem to work and either I'm Googling the totally wrong things or this doesn't happen all that often as I cannot find a solution.  Here's the screenshot;

[image]

**What have I tried;**

1. Yum check runs (takes ages but gets there eventually) and just returns;

   ```
   Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
   check all
   ```
2. I've tried rerunning the command with the flag `--setopt=protected_multilib=false` as it suggests (or suggest not to do, I was desperate).  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong there syntactically but that throws the error;

   ```
   Unrecognized command line flag: '--setopt=protected_multilib=false' ( see: 'rvm usage' )
   ```
3. By trying the command `yum list libffi` it shows me the following (image below).  Namely that there is an installed package and an available package.  If I try to upgrade the installed package with `yum update libffi.x86_64`  it tells me *No Packages marked for Update*.  If I try to remove the uninstalled package using `yum remove libffi.i686` it tells me *Package(s) libffi.i686 available, but not installed. No Packages marked for removal*.

[image]

4. Updating everything with `yum update`, it tells me *No Packages marked for Update*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I got it sorted. I was hesitant to use the answer in this Stack;

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799047/trying-to-remove-yum-which-is-protected-in-centos

As there were comments suggesting yum itself ended up broken.  I tried it anyway;

```
rpm -e --nodeps libffi
```

And it uninstalled the offending libffi package.  Then

```
yum install libffi-devel
```

worked fine and I could carry on and install ruby no problem.

Comment: Just want say that I had the same problems and your suggestion worked fine. But I feel quite uncomfortable deleting a package that yum depends on. Maybe someone can suggest a safer solution or explain, why this is not as dangerous as it sounds.

Comment: @Sascha - I totally agree.  Felt like a right dirty way to do things, be great if somebody gives a nice clean answer to this question!